# How to not focus element on application startup?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

Simplest application possible:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    ...>
    <Grid>
        <TextBox />
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Question: is there any elegant way to prevent the cursor (focus) from being set in the TextBox on application start up?

To expand: My real issue is that I have a PopUp that is opened when the TextBox receives focus. If I click on an element in my PopUp it should close, but since the TextBox is the first focusable element in my page it automatically receives focus and thus the PopUp immediately opens again. The core of the problem I think is represented by the example above.

Comment: What elements *can* you set the focus on? Or is the textbox the only control on your site?

Comment: @HimBromBeere I guess that it's possible to programmatically set focus on the next element in line after the TextBox. But then I have a (in my opinion) quite arbitrary and not so elegant solution. In the best of worlds no control would be focused until I clicked it or pressed tab. But maybe that's not the way things work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Focus is managed by various properties like `IsTabStop`, `TabIndex`, `IsHitTestVisible`, and the `FocusManager` class. There is built-in functionality to focus the first focusable element once the window is activated, and this behavior is generally not customizable.

We could designate a different element to be focused instead of the textbox like, say, the page itself:

```
<Page IsTabStop="True">
    <TextBox/>
</Page>
```

This works in that the page gets initial focus instead of the textbox, but now the page participates in tabbing behavior, which is slightly undesirable.

Typically the framework will set focus to the RootScrollViewer when you click out of a focused control, even though the RootScrollViewer isn't a tab stop (so it can't receive focus by tabbing). If we can focus the RootScrollViewer upon page load, the framework will detect that *something has focus* and won't attempt to focus the first element.

```
<Page Loaded="onPageLoaded">
    <TextBox/>
</Page>
```

```
private ScrollViewer getRootScrollViewer()
{
    DependencyObject el = this;
    while (el != null && !(el is ScrollViewer))
    {
        el = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(el);
    }

    return (ScrollViewer)el;
}

private void onPageLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    getRootScrollViewer().Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```

This is the most "elegant" way that I know to prevent the textbox from getting focused automatically.

Comment: I used your RootScrollViewer code and wrapped it up in a behavior. Now any page that I want to disable the initial focus, I just attach the behavior to the page. Works like a charm. Thanks!